# Django help_text line length convention

Tags: python, django, conventions, pep8

I was wondering what the convention was for line length when inputting help_text and other hard-coded long lines into Python/Django. I have read PEP-8, where line length is covered for code and comments, however I am not sure how this applies for long strings of text.

This is the for the field 'explanation_text', and the help_text field option.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    explanation_text = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        help_text="Explanation text goes here. Candidates will be able to see this after they have taken a questionnaire. To change this, refer to the setting on questionnaire administration. Max length is 1000 characters.",
        max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could store the `help_text` string as a multi-line string using triple-quotation marks as follows:

```
help_text = """Explanation text goes here. Candidates will be able to see
             this after they have taken a questionnaire. To change this,
             refer to the setting on questionnaire administration. Max 
             length is 1000 characters."""
```

However, it might be more conventional to either:

- store the multi-line string in a constant at the top of your `models.py` file:

  ```
  HELP_TEXT = """Explanation text.....
           ..................
           """

  class Question(...):
      ...
      help_text = HELP_TEXT
  ```
- group all of your constants together in a `constants.py` file. In `models.py` you would then have:

  ```
  import constants

  class Question(...):
      ...
      help_text = constants.HELP_TEXT
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much, I cant upvote yet as I dont have a high enough reputation. I think actually the first example you gave is the one I will go for as it will fit more neatly with the rest of the project.

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: I came here looking for `help_text` to be multiline when _displayed_ in the browser. Got that with HTML `<br>` tag. E.g.: `Date format: <em>DD/MM/YYYY</em>.<br>Time format: <em>HH:MM</em> (24 hours)`

Answer (score 6):

As maazza said, there is no convention.

As far as I'm concerned I like to use python implicit string concatenation.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    explanation_text = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        help_text=(
            "Explanation text goes here. Candidates will be able to see "
            "this after they have taken a questionnaire. To change this, "
            "refer to the setting on questionnaire administration. "
            "Max length is 1000 characters."),
        max_length=1000)
```

Which works cleanly when using gettext:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Question(models.Model):
    explanation_text = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Explanation text goes here. Candidates will be able to see "
            "this after they have taken a questionnaire. To change this, "
            "refer to the setting on questionnaire administration. "
            "Max length is 1000 characters."),
        max_length=1000)
```

Note: By the way, [this his how django do](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L215-L218).

Comment: nice tip and it fits the PEP-8 80-character recommendations

Answer (score 3):

> Extra “help” text to be displayed with the form widget. It’s useful
>   for documentation even if your field isn’t used on a form.
>
> Note that this value is not HTML-escaped in automatically-generated
>   forms. This lets you include HTML in help_text if you so desire. For
>   example:
>
> help_text="Please use the following format: *YYYY-MM-DD*."
>
> Alternatively you can use plain text and django.utils.html.escape() to
>   escape any HTML special characters. Ensure that you escape any help
>   text that may come from untrusted users to avoid a cross-site
>   scripting attack.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#help-text

There is no rule for it for it is only used to provide extra information to the user/developer (line length requirements are different on mobile and desktop for example)